# How to fix 'get table schema from server' error in Hive

Tags: hive, dsn

I'm using Microsoft Hive ODBC driver to connect hive server. An error occurred while I'm trying to execute `'select * from tb limit 100'` using a table `'tb'` with schema csv and a partition key. Other table without partition key can execute successfully.

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (97) Error occurred while trying to
>   get table schema from server. Error: [Microsoft][Hardy] (35) Error
>   from server: error code: '0' error message:
>   'MetaException(message:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Storage schema reading not supported)'.

Answer (score 2):

Add below configuration under "Custom hive-site":

***metastore.storage.schema.reader.impl=org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.SerDeStorageSchemaReader***

It worked for me.
Note: Restart affected services after saving the configuration.